# collecting random twitter conversations with criteria

Tags: twitter, tweets

I need to collect "sets" of tweets, i.e., twitter conversations for my research;

The sets also need to satisfy the criteria of

- the number of tweets in it, and
- the number of participants in it.

I've looked at Twitter Streaming API, twitter-stream gem, but I found none of them fitting for my purpose.

Is there any easy way to achieve this goal?

Comment: Are you mining for relevant comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's your starting point? How will you tell if a tweet matches your criteria?

Once you've done that, it's fairly simple.

- Get the tweet that is the starting point for the conversation.
- Search for replies to that tweet.

  - Twitter won't let you search "in_reply_to" but you can search for everyone mentioning "@user" and filter by "in_reply_to"
- Repeat recursively.

You'll end up with a tree with the starting tweet as the root node.  You should be able to traverse the tree to see how many unique users there are and how many tweets there are.

Comment: Is there a recommended tool? Or should I just deal with twitter API myself? Will twitter Streaming API alone be good enough to do it?

Comment: The regular API will allow you to extract specific tweets and replies.  What language are you planning on using?

Comment: most likely Python. Can it also extract random tweets and its replies, without specific query? I also heard that there's a mandated pause of 28 seconds between each tweet retrieval, which would elongate the process immensely. Is there a workaround for that, or is it inevitable? Thank you very much for your reply by the way.

Comment: Yes, there is a "sample" API call - https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/sample - as for 28 seconds, I've never heard of that and the documents don't mention it (although there may be other rate limits) https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#6861

Comment: Thanx, I'll give you the bounty in 16 hours :) 
Btw, Are the tweet retrievals usually done by URL request as in your link? If I were to use Python to use twitter api, would it be good idea?

Comment: You will need to make an HTTP request - you can do that directly in Python or using a helper library.

Comment: For an interesting project built with Python that is using Twitter Streaming API, see http://blog.comsysto.com/2012/07/10/real-time-twitter-heat-map-with-mongodb/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have same purpose with me, and I've made some python codes for it.
https://github.com/song9446/twitter-corpus-crawler-python

usage:

```python
from tccp import search_conversation
# fetch 10 conversations in english
for conversation in search_conversation({"l": "en"}, 10): 
    for tweet in conversation:
        print(tweet["author"] + ": " + tweet["contents"])
```

though it is an old thread, I hope that this helps somebody.